# Running NUnit Tests from Team city

Tags: nunit, teamcity, teamcity-5.1

I've successfully managed to get MSTests running for each of the builds on our TeamCity Server.

I've got a couple of projects that use NUnit, so was hoping that getting TeamCity to run NUnit tests would be as simple as running MSTests:

[image: MS Test Settings in Team City]

So when I try to do the same for my NUnit Tests the Testing Tab doesn't show up when the Build finishes, so I'm guessing it hasn't run my tests.

[image: Nunit Test Settings in Team City]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Not sure if this will help, but this is from the build log:

```
[Project "AssemblyName.proj.teamcity.patch.tcprojx" (Build;TeamCity_Generated_NUnitTests target(s)):] C:\Program Files\TeamCity\buildAgent\plugins\dotnetPlugin\bin\JetBrains.BuildServer.NUnitLauncher.exe "@@" "C:\Program Files\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\tmp2867.tmp"
[13:22:57]: Start TeamCity NUnit Test Runner
[13:22:59]: Build finished
```

It's like it starts the nunit build runner, then just stops?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NUnit test assemblies path is resolved relative to solution file folder. Try adding %teamcity.build.checkoutDir% at the beginning.

Comment: Hi, Perfect.. thanks adding that gave me a much cleared error message and I was able to get the "Tests" tab back again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the TeamCity Addin for NUnit?

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/TeamCity+Addin+for+NUnit

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. However I've checked all the documentation and I'm still stuck. I'm actually using team city 5.1 which has this addin built in. Thanks anyway. Dave